# PHP - unlink file if user quits web page?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I've created a webpage that requires users to fill out a form, which includes uploading an image. To allow the users to view the uploaded image without refreshing the page, I store the image in a temporary directory using AJAX. If the form is not filled out correctly, on submission the image in the temporary directory gets deleted. However, if the user closes their web browser or refreshes the page after uploading the image without submitting the form, it stays in the temporary directory.

Is there a way of detecting whether the user has quit/refreshed the page and subsequently unlinking the image file in the temporary directory?

Comment: You can probably use cookies/sessions/token with a (default) timeout value.

Comment: say I was to set `$_SESSION['timeout'] = false` and only if the user submits the post does is change to `true`. How would I execute code such as `if(!$_SESSION['timeout']) {//delete temp image}` when the user quits the page (would be easy when the user refreshes..)? thanks

Comment: There's no reliable way to know if the visit ended. You should just put the files either in the system tmp folder, in which case they will get delete eventually, or in a folder where you do the cleaning yourself. Just be sure to check the timestamp on the files so you only delete files there are older than 1 day or so, thus making sure you won't delete the temp files that are currently in use.

Comment: The simpliest method that works always is to create a cronjob to delete all images older then `n minutes`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Due to the nature of the client-server communication in HTTP there is no "simple" way to do that.

The best practice would be to store the image in a temporary directory and then to either store a timestamp with the image and run a job that deletes all images older than 30 minutes (or whatever timeout you want) or link the image to the user-session and check if the session still exists - if the session dies for whatever reason, delete the image.

You can set session-handlers with

bool session_set_save_handler ( callback $open , callback $close , callback $read , callback $write , callback $destroy , callback $gc )

Use the destroy and gc handlers to delete the files.

You will have to call the script to define the session save handlers at least in every script that works with sessions. You could put the code in an include file and include it whenever needed, or use the auto_prepend_file directive in php.ini

If you are using jQuery you can bind to the beforeunload event:

```
$(window).bind("beforeunload", function() {
     //send a request to delete the file
}
```

You could of course also use Javascript to send keepalive-requests to your server (using AJAX for example) and delete the image when those keepalives stop. That would probably be the most difficult and unreliable method and I would not recommend it.

Comment: I like the session method and could see how it could be done if the user was to stay on the site (e.g. refreshing the page). However if the user was to close the browser i'm not sure how I would check the session variable and delete the image. any ideas?

Comment: I have edited the answer with information on handling session destruction and timeout (garbage collection).

Comment: exactly what I was looking for! Just one thing, where do I store the function to get executed when the session is destroyed or the 'garbage collection' purge runs? should it be in the php.ini file?

Answer (score 1):

Check this, [onunload](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.onunload). But the best way is to use a cron job that deletes the image after some time. It's difficult to find out in a reliable way if the user has quit the page.

Comment: This wouldn't get executed if the user had javascript turned off. I'll look into cron job. thanks